# How to use PostgreSQL 9.4 with django?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, psycopg2

Is there a way to use PostgreSQL version 9.4 with django framework?

Must I downgrade my version of psycopg2? If yes which psycopg supports PostgreSQL 9.4?

I'm getting an error that django supports only PostgreSQL 11 or higher

Comment: Why? That's not supported for at least a year, and probably even longer. (version 9 does not exist, it's 9.0 or 9.1 or 9.2 or 9.3 or 9.4 or 9.5 or 9.6)

Comment: Yes I edited my question, thank you, the pg database I need to use in my projet has 9.4, I can't update (I'm connection via SSH to this database)

Comment: It's not the `psycopg2` version, it's the Django version that you are using which doesn't support PostgreSQL 9.4. You'd have to downgrade all the way to Django 2.2 (I won't advice doing this, 2.2 has known vulnerabilities) if you want to use PostgreSQL 9.4: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/databases/#postgresql-notes